# Spring security logon active directory not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory

I have written a Spring bot web application that uses Spring security. I have 2 links that are used by two different groups of people. So I created three active directory groups for the users and admin respectively. My problem is people in one of the group are able to access the application but rest of the two groups cannot access the application.It says not authorized to view the page.

**My login configuration is**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    @ComponentScan("com.books.controller")
    public class LoginConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .hasAuthority("BookAdmin")
            .and()   
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rentBook")
            .hasAuthority("RentalBook")
            .and()   
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/buybook")
            .hasAuthority("BuyBook")
            .and()       
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rentBook")
            .hasAuthority("BookAdmin")
            .and()   
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/buyBook")
            .hasAuthority("BookAdmin")
        and().authorizeRequests().and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            ;
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
        {
            auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
        }
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
            return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
        } 
        @Bean
        public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("xxx.klc", "ldap://klcdc03");
            provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
            return provider;
        }
    }
```

Please find my **Controller class** below. It runs perfectly in my local machine. But when deployed in server it works only for the BookAdmin group. I dont have these groups listed out in any properties file

```
package com.tgw.gift.info.controller;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
     @RequestMapping("/")
       public String home(Model model, Authentication principal)
       {
          Set<String> authorities=listAuthorties(principal);

          if(authorities.contains("BookAdmin"))
          {
             return "index";
          } else {
             return "fail";
          }

       }


    private Set<String> listAuthorties(Authentication principal)
       {
          Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

          for(GrantedAuthority s: principal.getAuthorities()){
             set.add(s.getAuthority());
          }
          return set;
       }

    @RequestMapping("/buyBook")
    public String printDetails(Model model, Authentication principal){
         Set<String> authorities=listAuthorties(principal);

          if(authorities.contains("BuyBook"))
          {
              return "buyBook";
          } else if(authorities.contains("BookAdmin")){
              return "buyBook";
          } else{
              return "fail";
          }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/rentBook")
    public String printDetails(Model model, Authentication principal){
         Set<String> authorities=listAuthorties(principal);

          if(authorities.contains("RentalBook"))
          {
              return "rentBook";
          } else if(authorities.contains("RentalAdmin")){
              return "rentBook";
          } else{
              return "fail";
          }
    }
}

also this works fine when run locally, but not in server.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few typos.  I also removed the leading spaces to your description, to stop it looking like code.  And I bolded some key words using 2 asterisks.  Please explain what you mean by "it doesn't work for non-BookAdmin group"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one `authorizeRequests` and one `antmatcher` per URL:

```java
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasAuthority("BookAdmin")
                .antMatchers("/rentBook").hasAnyAuthority("RentalBook", "BookAdmin")
                .antMatchers("/buybook").hasAnyAuthority("BuyBook", "BookAdmin")
```

Comment: I have a question. After deploying this to the server, when I try to navigate to "/buyBook" it is moving in there. But when I try to enter some value and submit it, It keeps loading for sometime and throws Connection reset by peer and broken pipe exception. do you have any idea of why this is happening, Earlier I dint face this. But "/rentBook" link is working fine though

Comment: @sanvica Can't say. Try collect some more detail and ask it as a new question.